# xamarin.forms: tracking only user intiated changes

Tags: xamarin.forms

I cannot find a concept for a Xamarin.Forms app which meets the following requirement:

- any change to any value directly initiated by the user needs to be timestamped and tracked in a "table of changes"
- any change to any value not directly initiated by the user (e.g. changes stemming from screen initialization on application start, or updates pulled in by a background task) may not be tracked. Nevertheless they need to appear on screen.

Example: On the screen, there is a "Name" input. On application first load, the last name entered is pulled from some local persistency store, and written to screen, but this change is not logged.

Every now and then a background task queries a web service for "name", and if it finds one, name is overwritten on screen and in the persistency store. Both changes are not tracked, since they are not user initiated.

Once the user keys in a name, however, the value is stored in the persistency store, and the change ist tracked (timestamped and written to a "table of changes" in the local persistency store.

the same principle must be applicable to all Xamarin.forms controls, e.g. switches as well. If a "done" switch bound to a bool property is flipped by the user, the change needs to be tracked, if the switch is set during initialization or by background update it must not be tracked. I mention the switch control, because I have already ran into specific issues with the Xamarin.forms switch control described on SO and elsewhere (OnToggled unexpectedly fires if the underlying value is changed programmatically).

Anyone who can help? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the MVVM pattern, you could do the following:

Create an abstraction for logged viewmodels

```
public interface ILoggedViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    bool IsChangingProgrammatically { get; }
}
```

every viewmodel you have to log (which may well be every viewmodel) will implement this interface (including the `PropertyChanged` event, which is defined by `INotifyPropertyChanged`). When you create your viewmodels (a very good solution for that would be DI, e.g. with Prisms `ViewModelLocator` - maybe you'll have to register the viewmodels manually) you register them with a class that subscribes to the `PropertyChanged` event.

Before changing any property programmatically you set `IsChangingProgrammatically` to `true` and reset it afterwards (maybe in a `finally`-block, to prevent the property not being reset in case of an exception). Whenever the `PropertyChangedEvent` is raised, the handler on your logger will be called. Then the logger checks `IsChangingProgrammatically` on the sender and if it is `false` assumes that the change has been user-initiated and logs the activity.

**Edit:**

In order to make this work properly, you can't set `IsChangingProgrammatically` before starting a long-runnning operation and reset it afterwards, but only around setting the value, otherwise user interactions during the long-running operation won't be recorded.

```
private async void UpdateData()
{
    try
    {
        var data = await _repository.GetData();
        this.IsChangingProgrammatically = true;
        Data = data;
    }
    finally
    {
        this.IsChangingProgrammatically = false;
    }
}
```

**Edit 2:**

There is a way that avoids those timing issues. You could create a derivative from `PropertyChangedEventArgs` that is thrown to indicate that a property has been changed programmatically

```
class PropertyChangedProgrammaticallyEventArgs : PropertyChangedEventArgs
{
    public PropertyChangedProgrammaticallyEventArgs (string propertyName) : base(propertyName) { }
}
```

In your base viewmodel you declare something like

```
void ChangePropertyBackingField<T>(ref T backingField, string propertyName, T value)
{
    backingField = value;
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedProgrammaticallyEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

to create a special `PropertyChangedEventArgs` implementation when a property has changed programmatically, but still cause the UI to update. This way you can change programmatic changes from other changes in your logger

```
void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if(!(eventArgs is PropertyChangedProgrammaticallyEventArgs ))
    {
        // log user interaction
    }
}
```

Comment: I already had an approach like this, which failed for 2 Reasons: 
- once the background task fires up and starts to update items, the IsCachangingProgrammatically Flag is set. While the task hasn't finished, items changed by the user won't log.
- the same problem appears when the app does the initial read of the database.

Comment: According to your last edit: does setting IsCchangingProgrammatically around each separate item indeed solve the problem of lost user update logging? IMHO this approach does only reduce the possibility that user changes are missing in the log.

Comment: You won't be 100% sure that it does not happen, but I don't think that Xamarin.Forms is in any way equipped to perform a waterproof logging of user interaction, anyway. How likely it is, would depend on many factors, e.g. how often the values are changed programmatically.

Comment: @Nimral There is another possibility, please see my second edit. This way you should be able to discriminate user interactions from programmatic ones.

Comment: Thanks Paul for Edit2, haven't tried it yet, but it looks very promising. I'll let you know what happens if I test it.